# How to arrange the values in a column to a new column based on a condition and a substring?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, substring

I have a data frame including three columns as below. I need to add a new column based on the following condition:
If in `var_field`, the string following `$` equals the string in `text`, put the corresponding value in `var` in the new column called `new_col`. When `text` equals NA, the `new_col` should remain NA as well. I would really appreciate your advice.

| var | text | var_field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | happy | A$excited |
| B | sad | B$angry |
| C | angry | C$sad |
| D | excited | D$happy |
| E | NA | E$nervous |
| F | NA | F$blue |
| G | NA | G$lonely |

The expected new column should look like column "new_col".

| var | text | var_field | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | happy | A$excited | D |
| B | sad | B$angry | C |
| C | angry | C$sad | B |
| D | excited | D$happy | A |
| E | NA | E$nervous | NA |
| F | NA | F$blue | NA |
| G | NA | G$lonely | NA |

Comment: Does each option for `text` (except the NAs) only appear once in the `text` column?

Comment: @Paul Stafford Allen That's a good point I forgot to mention. No they are not unique.

Comment: If they are duplicated, how would you choose which value to take across to `new_col`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1st(!) match in base R:

```r
df_ <- read.table(header = T, text = "
var text    var_field
A   happy   A$excited
B   sad B$angry
C   angry   C$sad
D   excited D$happy
E   NA  E$nervous
F   NA  F$blue
G   NA  G$lonely")


suffix <- sapply(strsplit(df_$var_field, "$", fixed = TRUE), `[`, 2)
df_$new_col <- df_$var[match(df_$text, suffix)]
df_
#>   var    text var_field new_col
#> 1   A   happy A$excited       D
#> 2   B     sad   B$angry       C
#> 3   C   angry     C$sad       B
#> 4   D excited   D$happy       A
#> 5   E    <NA> E$nervous    <NA>
#> 6   F    <NA>    F$blue    <NA>
#> 7   G    <NA>  G$lonely    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I hadn't thought that `match()` would return `NA` if there were no matches - that's handy.

Comment: match() was all I needed. Very simple and neat solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, using various `tidyverse` functions.

Set up test data:

```
testdata <- tribble(
~var, ~text, ~var_field,
"A",    "happy",    "A$excited",
"B",    "sad",  "B$angry",
"C",    "angry",    "C$sad",
"D",    "excited",  "D$happy",
"E",    NA, "E$nervous",
"F",    NA, "F$blue",
"G",    NA, "G$lonely")
```

create a reference for which `text` returns which `var`

```
lookup <- as_vector(testdata$var)
names(lookup) <- testdata$text
```

then do the creation of the new column

```
testdata %>% mutate(
  field_text = str_extract(var_field, "(?<=\\$)(.*)"), #drop the leading character and "$"
  new_col = case_when(
    is.na(text) ~ NA_character_,
    .default = lookup[field_text]
  ) # created the new_col as per spec
) %>% 
  select(-field_text) # drop the simplified var_field as no longer needed
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  var   text    var_field new_col
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>     <chr>  
1 A     happy   A$excited D      
2 B     sad     B$angry   C      
3 C     angry   C$sad     B      
4 D     excited D$happy   A      
5 E     NA      E$nervous NA     
6 F     NA      F$blue    NA     
7 G     NA      G$lonely  NA
```

Edit: this assumes that the non-NA options under `text` are unique, which is not correct according to OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
quux %>%
  mutate(text2 = sub(".*\\$", "", var_field)) %>%
  left_join(quux, by = c(text2 = "text"), suffix = c("", ".y"), multiple = "first") %>%
  mutate(new_col2 = var.y) %>%
  select(-ends_with(".y"), -text2)
#   var    text var_field new_col new_col2
# 1   A   happy A$excited       D        D
# 2   B     sad   B$angry       C        C
# 3   C   angry     C$sad       B        B
# 4   D excited   D$happy       A        A
# 5   E    <NA> E$nervous    <NA>     <NA>
# 6   F    <NA>    F$blue    <NA>     <NA>
# 7   G    <NA>  G$lonely    <NA>     <NA>
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(var = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), text = c("happy", "sad", "angry", "excited", NA, NA, NA), var_field = c("A$excited", "B$angry", "C$sad", "D$happy", "E$nervous", "F$blue", "G$lonely"), new_col = c("D", "C", "B", "A", NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
library(data.table)

as.data.table(tstrsplit(df$var_field, "$",fixed = T))[
  df, on=.(V2 = text)][, .(var, text=V2,var_field,new_col=V1)]
```

Output:

```
      var    text var_field new_col
   <char>  <char>    <char>  <char>
1:      A   happy A$excited       D
2:      B     sad   B$angry       C
3:      C   angry     C$sad       B
4:      D excited   D$happy       A
5:      E    <NA> E$nervous    <NA>
6:      F    <NA>    F$blue    <NA>
7:      G    <NA>  G$lonely    <NA>
```